# Finiteness of $m$-torsion points in elliptic curves

Tags: galois-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I'm reading the proof of lemma 1.1.1 (setion VIII) in Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*:

[image]

[image]

I have two questions:

1) Why does he assume that the $m$-torsion subgroup $E[m]$ is finite? Is it obvious? I haven't found any mention of that earlier in the book.

2) Right after the proof he says that lemma 1.1.1 allows the assumption that $E[m]\subset E(K)$. Why?

Comment: The structure of $E[m]$ is earlier in the book: Cor. 6.4 in chapter III (2nd ed.) We can assume that $E[m]\subset E(K)$ by replacing $K$ by $L$ where $L$ is obtained by adjoining coordinates of all points in $E[m]$.

Comment: Yes it is obvious that $E(\overline{K})[m]$ is finite for $E : y^2 = x^3+ax+b$ because $[m]P = 0 $ is a finite dimensional rational equation in $(x_P,\sqrt{x_P^3+ax_P+b})$ ie. a polynomial equation in $x_P$, which has only finitely many roots in $\overline{K}$. If this polynomial is separable then we obtain the number of roots and hence the cardinality  and the group structure of each $E[m]$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, by adjoining the points in $E[m]$ to $K$ do we get a finite extension $L/K$?

Comment: @AguirreK Yes, there are only finitely many points in $E[m]$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, but the fact that $E [m]$ is finite only implies the extension is finitely generated, right?  (for example, $\mathbb{Q} (\pi)/\mathbb{Q}$ is finitely generated but not finite)

Comment: @AguirreK But the coordinates of each point of $E[m]$ are algebraic over $K$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, one last question: how do we prove $K(E[m])/K$ is Galois?